# ReportScore method obsolete for Game Center API

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, game-center, xamarin-studio

I'm looking at the monotouch samples available, and for the [PlayerModel class](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/GameCenterSample/GameCenterSample/PlayerModel.cs), it has this code (line 55):

```
GKScore score = new GKScore (storedScores.ValueAt ((uint)index));
score.ShouldSetDefaultLeaderboard = true;
if (score == null)
    return;

score.ReportScore (new GKNotificationHandler( (error) => ..
```

However, Xamarin Studio is saying that ReportScore is obsolete.  However, I'm finding blogs on iOS 7 that still use this method.  So is this the correct approach to report a score, or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `ReportScores`?

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.GameKit.GKScore%2fM%2fReportScores

Obviously it maps to the Objective-C ones that are not obsolete,

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009601-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4

Comment: For Xamarin it's ReportScore and ReportScoreAsync; I assumed that ReportScore would have mapped to Objective-C ReportScores... I also half-wonder if the obsolete flag was added in error...  Thanks.

Comment: The obsolete flag is not added in error, as Apple also states the underlying API (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009601-CH1-SW1) as obsolete, . You should use `ReportScores` static method of `GKScore` as I stated above.